# What does 尿が近い and 尿が遠い mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

seeing 尿が遠い/尿が近い in some medical documents and sites, what does 遠い and 近い mean in this sense? Does it literally mean the urine is far(ranged)/urine is close (ranged)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, 「[近]{ちか}い」 and 「[遠]{とお}い」 express temporal intervals and not spatial distances -- "at shorter intervals" and "at longer intervals", respectively.

「[尿]{にょう}が近い」 means "having the tendency of urinating frequently".

「尿が遠い」 means the opposite of that -- "not having to pee very often".

We also say euphemistically 「トイレが近い/遠い」 to express the exact same ideas without using the word 「尿」(= "urine").

(Needless to say, 「トイレが近い/遠い」 can also be used for their "literal" meanings -- "The restroom is close by / far away.")

Comment: Just adding that in my experience, 尿が遠い is not used much. But 尿が近い, トイレが近い and also オシッコが近い are pretty common phases for older people.